# Allow scrolling when shrinkwrap is set to true

Tags: list, flutter, shrinkwrap

When i use ListView, i got the following error:

```
RenderBox was not laid out
```

one of the solutions for this problem is to set shrinkwrap attribute to true:

```
 shrinkWrap: true,
```

The problem is that the scrolling of the listview do not work when i set `shrinkWrap` to true,and only the scrolling is only allowable outside area of listview.

How can i make the scrolling to work inside listview when `shrinkWrap` is set to true

Comment: It's really hard to tell without some more code of how your widgets are structured. Could you paste some of your code?

Comment: can you please add code, so we find the actual issue